# How to to set template for default handle in local.xml

Tags: xml, magento

I am trying to set template for root block in default handle in local.xml file.But when I reload the page , it's not applying. This is the screenshot of my page i am working:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/00c56brc13

I tried to upload xml in editor but it's showing error.

Here is my local.xml

https://www.dropbox.com/s/397dzuv5afhqn87/local.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure Magento's actually loading your layout XML.  Put Magento [in "developer mode" and make sure `display_errors` is set to `1`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15482/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-magento-1-7).  Then, deliberately introduce an unclosed tag into your layout XML.  If Magento compains about the error, you'll know the file is being loaded.  It it does not, you'll know the problem is Magento's loading a different `local.xml`.

If Magento **is** loading your layout, the problem may be **other** layout XML updates that set the template.

Finally, if you're on a CMS page, and have used the UI to select a templates -- these settings will override **any** other attempts to set a template programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested and local.xml is loaded. I can change cms page layout using admin section. But i want to overwrite it using local.xml. But overwrite code is not working. Is there any solution?